# List of Applications on my iphone in Foundation Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, foundation

I wonder how I can get a list of applications installed on my iphone from Objective-C (Foundation Framework).
Does anyone can help me?

I also wanted to know if you can launch an app from within my application.

Thank you very much to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible as far as i know. Application are sandboxed in the iOS and there is not such API to retrieve the list of installed apps ...

Comment: It is only possible if you are jailbroken, because then you can access the Sandboxed directories.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine which applications are installed on iPhone.
But, there's a thing called URL Schemes, some applications registers those and you can communicate with them.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html